# error occurred on running composer playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

**I had installed my business network and then successfully started it. Then I opened my composer playground from the command line. After opening it is showing the below message what should I do?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you have installed composer-playground as root or using sudo or su.

The composer install instructions state that you should not use su/sudo.

There is additional information about installing composer in the [Knowledge wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues), but if you are having permissions problems trying to install without root/su/sudo please see this [link from the npm site](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Comment: Yes I had problem so I used "sudo" for installation. I will try this link. hope that will help.

Comment: Please tell me how installing with "sudo" can cause error?

Comment: check NPM docs - or see these blogs https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3  (reason 2) and https://givan.se/do-not-sudo-npm/ for more insights. Composer does not support installing its npm modules using root or sudo.